# What are the different versions of c++ and how to know which one is suitable for what purpose?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have learned vc++ followed by mfc.
Now there is this other version of c++/cli which is for.net

Additionally there are different versions of c++ 11, 14, 17.

Why is there no clear distinction between all of these versions.

I have read c++ Standard template library.

Now again there is a different stl version for each c++ versions.

Comment: The numbers just refer to the years the different standards were published. The later versions are presumably better than the earlier. There's no special purpose behind any of them. MFC is a library, and VC++ is a compiler, so these aren't really comparible to the language itself.

Comment: Just use newest, unless your project requires otherwise (e.g. it was written in legacy way and you cannot just update it).

Comment: There's a lot of distinction between the various versions. The C++ standard runs to about two thousand pages of terse, technical text, for each one of the versions you mentioned, and there are notable difference from version to version. It's not realistic to expect to read a capsule summary of the differences between three versions of a two thousand page text in just a paragraph, or two, on stackoverflow.com. If you would like to know what the differences are, the only way to do so is to do a lot of reading. A lot. P.S. there's also C++20. Add another two thousand pages on top of this.

Comment: C++/CLI is not a version of C++, it's a different language that derived from C++.  Sort of like C++ is not a version of C, it's a different language that derived from C.  Or Objective-C++ is not a version of C++, it's a different language that derived from C++ and Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see different features added in each version here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp

The general answer is they are all suitable for all the same things that C++ is suitable for. People will disagree, but overall you would use them for the same things, the newer versions just add newer features that are "nice" but not required to do any task.

Comment: That is a helpful article but how to actually determine which version is suitable for what

Comment: You don't, they can all do the same things the only difference is what options you have for typing those things out. A lot of the newer features just save you time typing things yourself  (sometimes at the cost of readability), or make it easier to avoid mistakes.

The one place you _might_ care is ABI compatibility. If any version breaks ABI compat then you cannot use a library from that version in the other versions. As far as I know, none of these versions break ABI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I am quite satisfied with DClyde's answer.

C++/ CLI is the variant of C++ that runs in the .NET environment, and you can use it, along with other languages such as C#, to create rich desktop applications.

C++ 17 & 20 have some new features included.

There is a great book to learn the new features of c++ 17 & 20:

Expert C++: Become a proficient programmer by learning coding best practices with C++17 and C++20's latest features.

I think DClyde deserves to clear the confusion and has answered the question with proved article that is really handy.

Thanks buddy.